# Logo file gets chopped when uploaded to the web

Tags: logo, svg, file-format, adobe-xd

I have made up a logo in Adobe XD that looks like this:

[image]

(Don't mind the line at the top of the screenshot)

But when I try to upload it to google drive, it looks like this:

[image]

I never had this problem before with .svg files. I don't undertand how just uploading a file to the web changes it.

Here's a link to the [google drive .svg file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IWvXfp9pITnccwvBtt-SDSUTapX7jvmv/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outline the font.

Dolce-Regular, Dolce are not a common typefaces and **not** included in your SVG file.

```
   <text id="YogaMatch" transform="translate(221.04 68.3)" fill="#707070" font-size="44" font-family="Dolce-Regular, Dolce"><tspan x="0" y="0">YogaMatch</tspan></text>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know why the logo is pixelated as well? Sorry if this is basic stuff - I am a programmer, not designer.

Comment: @BarAkiva - google drive isn't displaying the SVG, only a low resolution raster preview.  The SVG is not pixelated.